# Default landing page of error 404 inside certain directory level

Tags: php, javascript, url

I want to use URL as a textbox, the same concept as run.exe in windows.

For example I manually input in URL this www.directory.com/dirlevel/444

the problem now is that www.directory.com/dirlevel/444 don't exist (Error 404)

How can I set default landing page inside /dirlevel/ like default.php to replace Error page

and get parameters from URL?

Comment: you mean you want to forward to default.php when page not found is encountered ? what is your Web Server ? Dreamweaver is just a web authoring software, while Oracle is a database software. Not related.

Comment: i'm using apache server. i asked this several times and the answers has something to do with mod_rewrite or in **.htaccess**. anyway can i just add **"?"** but not visible like **dirlevel/444** while the actual is  **dirlevel/?444**.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is 'routing', telling your web server how to respond to requests based on the URL. The default routing you have is probably set up to look for PHP or HTML files and process and serve those, but depending on what server software you are using you should be able to change this.

Assuming you are hosting on an apache server, you should be able to achieve this with **mod_rewrite**. A search for how to use **mod_rewrite** gave this article: http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Comment: is there other solution without involving .htaccess? cause i got limited access here and i need to request to admin first before doing something on .htaccess.

Comment: My suspicion is that it would be very hard to do so without access to that file. It may be possible that some matching patterns have already been set up that you could use, or that you could get the admin of your server to set some up for you. Otherwise I think the only way would be using query string parameters, but I would love to be proven wrong.

Comment: `.htaccess` does not require admin rights. It's just a file uploaded to the directory.

Comment: As Shivan mentions, as long as you have access to the folder `dirlevel` then you should be able to create an .htaccess file inside the folder that rewrites the url `444` to `somepage.php?something=444`